# ¿Cómo identificar los archivos faltantes en función de sus nombres de archivo en Python?

Tags: python-3.x, archivo, rutas, timestamp

Sucede que tengo una carpeta ubicada en

`C:\Users\StoreX\Downloads\Binance futures data\AliceUSDT-Mark_Prices_Klines_1h_Timeframe`

que solo contiene 253 archivos csv con los siguientes nombres de archivo:

```
1. ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-01.csv
2. ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-02.csv
3. ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-03.csv
4. ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-06.csv
5. ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-09.csv
6. ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-11.csv
7. ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-12.csv
.
.
.
253. ALICEUSDT-1h-2022-02-13.csv
```

Cada uno de esos archivos contiene la acción del precio por hora de un activo en particular, con un total de 24 filas (sin nombres de columnas) y, por lo tanto, se puede suponer que **cada nombre de archivo corresponde a los datos de acción del precio tomados para un activo en particular en un fecha particular**.

Sin embargo, si observa detenidamente el ejemplo anterior, faltan algunos archivos al principio, que son:

```
ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-04.csv
ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-05.csv
ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-07.csv
ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-08.csv
ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-10.csv
```

Obviamente, esto significa que no puedo tener en cuenta los archivos que son anteriores a los archivos que faltan para desarrollar una estrategia de trading.

Entonces, primero tendría que detectar qué archivos faltan en función de su nombre, para luego definir dónde comenzar a trazar la acción del precio para evitar todas las posibles brechas.

**Actualización: Esto es lo que he logrado hasta ahora**:

```
import os
import datetime

def check_path(infile):
    return os.path.exists(infile)   

first_entry = input('Tell me the path where your csv files are located at:')

while True:
    
    if check_path(first_entry) == False:
        print('\n')
        print('This PATH is invalid!')
        first_entry = input('Tell me the RIGHT PATH in which your csv files are located: ')
        
    elif check_path(first_entry) == True:
        print('\n')
        final_output = first_entry
        break

for name in os.listdir(first_entry):
    if name.endswith(".csv"):
        print((name.partition('-')[-1]).partition('-')[-1].removesuffix(".csv"))
```

Salida:

```
2021-06-01
2021-06-02
2021-06-03
2021-06-06
2021-06-09
.
.
.
2022-02-13
```

¿Algunas ideas?

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo?

Comment: Sí, ya he podido dar con un programa que imprima exclusivamente las fechas que contienen los nombres de los archivos @aeportugal

Comment: Ahora, lo que no sé es cómo identificar las fechas faltantes dentro de toda esa serie de fechas que acabo de sacar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si esos archivos tienen siempre el mismo formato, solo cambia la fecha, entonces una forma sencilla sería listar todos los archivos, se extrae el menor y el mayor elemento, y se usan de límites para la generación de fecha.

```
import glob, datetime

filesFound = glob.glob1(r"aqui/va/la/ruta", '*.csv')
filesFound.sort()
date_start  = filesFound[0][-14:-4] # Fecha del primer elemento
date_finish = filesFound[-1][-14:-4] # Fecha del último elemento

curr_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_start, '%Y-%m-%d')
end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_finish, '%Y-%m-%d')

filesNotFound = []
while curr_date < end_date:
    filename = 'ALICEUSDT-1h-{}.csv'.format(curr_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    if filename not in filesFound:
        filesNotFound.append(filename)
    curr_date += datetime.timedelta(days=1) # fecha actual +1 día

print(filesNotFound) # <-- archivos faltantes.
```

Utilicé el módulo nativo [glob](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+glob&oq=python+glob), el cual es versátil para listar archivos buscando patrones en sus nombres. Pero igual se puede de [muchas otras formas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory). Si los nombres de los archivos tienen otras variantes, entonces con mayor razón te puede servir glob.

Comment: Ya veo, muchas gracias señor @aeportugal, le aprecio la respuesta.